# crispy forms tailwind with tabs

Tags: django, tailwind-css, django-crispy-forms

I want to have a form with 3 tabs using cripsyformws and tailwind.
for now it does not work:
my html:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% load tailwind_filters %}

{% block content %}

<div class="max-w-lg mx-auto">
    <div class="py-5 border-t border-gray-200">
        <h1 class="text-4xl text-gray-800">Create a new company</h1>
    </div>
    <form method="post" class="mt-5">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ form|crispy }}
        <button type='submit' class="w-full text-white bg-blue-500 hover:bg-blue-600 px-3 py-2 rounded-md">
            Submit
        </button>
    </form>
</div>

{% endblock content %}
```

my form:

```
class CompanyModelForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Company
        fields = '__all__'


    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.helper = FormHelper()
        self.helper.form_tag = False
        self.helper.layout = Layout(
            TabHolder(
                Tab('company_name' ,
            'fiscal_end_of_year' ,
                    ),
                Tab('Addrfirm_address',
                    'Addrfirm_code',
                    'Addrfirm_country',
                    'Addrfirm_city',
                    'Addrfirm_state'
                    ),
                Tab('AddrShipping_address',
                    'AddrShipping_code',
                    'AddrShipping_country',
                    'AddrShipping_city',
                    'AddrShipping_state'
                    ),
                Tab('AddrInvoice_address',
                    'AddrInvoice_code',
                    'AddrInvoice_country',
                    'AddrInvoice_city',
                    'AddrInvoice_state'
                    )
            )
        )
        self.helper.layout.append(Submit('submit', 'Submit'))
```

My goal is to have 3 tabs for the same form tab1 general info, tab2 shipping address, tab3 invoicing address.
Do tailwind permit this with crispy or how should I do this if not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this in your html, ie load the crispy_forms_tags and then render the tabbed form using {% crispy form %}.
You'll then add CSS rules based on how Django renders that form on HTML.

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% load tailwind_filters %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}

{% block content %}
<div class="max-w-lg mx-auto">
    <div class="py-5 border-t border-gray-200">
        <h1 class="text-4xl text-gray-800">Create a new company</h1>
    </div>
    <form method="post" class="mt-5">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {% crispy form %}
    </form>
</div>

{% endblock content %}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add {% load crispy_fotms_tags %} on the top of your page
And add crispy_foms
to your settings. Py